# InDesign Workspace does not show numbers and fonts anymore

Tags: adobe, flash-cs5, adobe-indesign

since yesterday im having trouble with my InDesign. I cant see any typo or any numbers of positions and other things anymore whether i use CS 5.5 or CS 6. It alwys looks like this:

[image]

[image]

It would be great if someone had a solution for this problem.

greetings

Comment: i reinstalled the whole adobe suit and nothing happend. looks like on the picture above.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried resetting the workspace or creating a new workspace from any defaults?

Sample Indesign workspace menu:

[image: Indesign workspace menu]

Comment: already tried this. after reinstallation (which didnt work at all) and some phone calls with adobe i made a new admin-user on my mac and reinstalled the adobe suite on this user. Now it works. No one (not even the people at adobe) could tell me what the problem was/is.